# Error: Not a HASH reference

Tags: perl, hash

I have pieve of code that I am trying to assign the return value but I see the following error. Appreciate if someone can let me know why am I getting this error.

Error: Not a HASH reference at  line

```
sub getid {
   my ($a, $b) = @_;
   my $id = 1 << $a + 1 << $b;
   return $id;
}

my $tip;
$tip->{'tock'}->[0]->{'brick'} = getid(2, 3);  <== This is where I am having issue.
```

Comment: Why would anyone give negative marks if I am trying to understand how to get things working in perl. I am a noob still.

Comment: Your question got downvoted because the code you provided does not produce the error you claim it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the code you actually ran to get that error. In your actual code, `$tip` or `$tip->{'tock'}->[0]` is defined but doesn't hold a reference to a hash. Print them out to find out which.

It might be useful to dump your data structure to figure out what it actually is.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print(Dumper($tip));
```